# 405 HEAD python 3.5 instead of GET 200

Tags: python

just was monitoring logs of my web application on python 3.5, and i see a lot of request are going to HEAD 405 instead of GET, i was surprised.

Does that means something wrong with my application, it's that a bug or is a normal behavior?

```
[W 180504 14:45:07 web:2063] 405 HEAD /login/ (ip_1) 5.26ms
[I 180504 14:45:27 web:2063] 200 GET /login/ (ip_1) 4.77ms
```

As from example i see in my logs, first entry with HEAD method is first and after a while is coming next log with same IP but is GET as it have to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does that means something wrong with my application, it's that a bug or is a normal behavior?

Looks like your application is functioning normally.

If your endpoint is required to support HEAD HTTP method, then it's a bug on your side. But if you know nothing about this, then it's client's problem.

It could be a bug on the front end side. Or it could be a hacker trying to find out if your endpoint supports this method and if he could find a security hole using it.

Comment: The application do not have HEAD method used, only supports GET, POST and DELETE, means is client side problem? But can be done somehow that is somebody trying to get on HEAD to redirect them on GET?

Comment: The concept of redirect works only for URLs. HTTP method as part of the request itself. If this bothers you, implement HEAD method in your code -- just call the GET implementation and return the generated response stripping the body.

Comment: thanks, is not bothering me, just wanted to be sure that no problem with the application